# Prop default gets overwritten in all mount-instances as soon as prop is passed once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-props

I have a `my-component.vue` which sets a `prop default` to `true`:

```
const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: String,
    editable: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
})
```

I'd assume now that whenever the component is imported and mounted, its `editable` prop is set to `true` if no no other value is passed as prop but as soon as I pass:

```
<my-component :editable="false"/>
```

in any of the parent components, the `editable` prop inside `my-component` is permanently set to `false` in all instances of mounting it.

Is that the desired behaviour of `default props` or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a bug somewhere, the default prop shouldn't be overwritten by setting a prop value in a sibling.

As you can see in [this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UctuwyAQ/BXEJa0Uw90lkdqeK/UDuBB73RKZh2CdyrL494LjpFbUhNPu7GtmmOir9+w0AK2piE3QHkkEHPxeWm28C0g+xneXIwsWSRecIRvGV1gZ3kgr+Hk6z+UEwfheIZQMhRmr5rqihlajOvSwk7RTfQRJCf+n7x4m+Go53dIzy8ooz47R2axjkpYQuRSipDWZkYJlriWX9BvRx5rz2DVFwDEyF754jlgYLGoDDKKpDsH9RAh5saRlRZI25ZM36u9bN5EWOm3hMzgfSVrsK4a9zBxt42xE4ufybt38tFC+mHXVUB6OPgNvzvWg7PYPz/Nq6LEmGLLOGS6Mnx/8jmj1aT9NlzMpCV6QW5vTL+RRwU0=) the default value is applied even though one of the siblings has `:editable="false"`

Comment: Weirdly, this experiment works for me too. There must be something else wrong.